# Create (many) columns conditional on similarly named columns

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to create a new column that take the value of one of two similarly named columns, depending on a third column. There are many such columns to create. Here's my data.

```
dt <- structure(list(malvol_left_1_w1 = c("1", "1", "4", "3", "4", 
"4", "1", "4", "4", "3", "1", "4", "4", "3", "4", "4", "5", "2", 
"4", "2"), malvol_left_2_w1 = c("1", "1", "4", "3", "4", "4", 
"1", "3", "4", "2", "2", "2", "4", "1", "5", "4", "5", "2", "4", 
"2"), malvol_right_1_w1 = c("1", "1", "4", "3", "4", "4", "1", 
"3", "4", "2", "1", "4", "4", "5", "5", "4", "2", "6", "4", "1"
), malvol_right_2_w1 = c("1", "1", "4", "3", "4", "4", "1", "3", 
"4", "2", "1", "2", "4", "5", "5", "4", "5", "5", "4", "5"), 
    malvol_left_1_w2 = c("1", "1", "3", "3", "4", "4", "1", "5", 
    "4", "4", "4", "2", "1", "4", "5", "4", "3", "2", "4", "4"
    ), malvol_left_2_w2 = c("1", "1", "3", "3", "4", "4", "7", 
    "5", "4", "2", "3", "1", "1", "4", "4", "4", "3", "4", "4", 
    "4"), malvol_right_1_w2 = c("1", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", 
    "1", "4", "4", "3", "2", "2", "4", "1", "4", "4", "5", "5", 
    "4", "4"), malvol_right_2_w2 = c("1", "2", "3", "3", "4", 
    "4", "1", "2", "4", "2", "3", "2", "4", "1", "4", "4", "5", 
    "4", "4", "3"), leftright_w1 = c("right", "right", "left", 
    "right", "right", "right", "left", "right", "right", "left", 
    "left", "left", "left", "right", "left", "left", "right", 
    "right", "right", "left"), leftright_w2 = c("right", "right", 
    "left", "left", "right", "left", "left", "right", "right", 
    "left", "left", "left", "left", "right", "left", "left", 
    "right", "right", "left", "left")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("12", 
"15", "69", "77", "95", "96", "112", "122", "150", "163", "184", 
"216", "221", "226", "240", "298", "305", "354", "370", "379"
))
```

Now I can do this in dplyr like:

```
dt <- dt %>% 
  mutate(
    malvol_1_w1 = case_when(
      leftright_w1 == "left" ~ malvol_right_1_w1, 
      leftright_w1 == "right" ~ malvol_left_1_w1),
    malvol_2_w1 = case_when(
      leftright_w1 == "left" ~ malvol_right_2_w1, 
      leftright_w1 == "right" ~ malvol_left_2_w1),
    malvol_1_w2 = case_when(
      leftright_w2 == "left" ~ malvol_right_1_w2, 
      leftright_w2 == "right" ~ malvol_left_1_w2),
    malvol_2_w2 = case_when(
      leftright_w2 == "left" ~ malvol_right_2_w2, 
      leftright_w2 == "right" ~ malvol_left_2_w2))
```

However, it's not really a feasible solution, because there will be more of both numbers defining a variable (e.g. both `malvol_3_w1` and `malvol_1_w3` will need to be created).

One solution is to this with a loop:

```
for (wave in 1:2) {
  for (var in 1:2) {
    dt[, paste0("malvol_", var, "_w", wave)] <- dt[, paste0("malvol_right_", var, "_w", wave)]
    dt[dt[[paste0("leftright_w", wave)]] == "right", paste0("malvol_", var, "_w", wave)] <- 
      dt[dt[[paste0("leftright_w", wave)]] == "right", paste0("malvol_left_", var, "_w", wave)]
  }
}
```

However, what is a tidyverse solution?

---

UPDATE:

I came up with a `tidyverse` solution myself, however, not every elegant. Still looking for more canonical solutions.

```
dt <- dt %>% 
  mutate(
    malvol_1_w1 = NA, malvol_2_w1 = NA, 
    malvol_1_w2 = NA, malvol_2_w2 = NA) %>%
  mutate(
    across(matches("malvol_\\d"), 
           ~ case_when(
             eval(parse(text = paste0("leftright_",  str_extract(cur_column(), "w.")))) == "left" ~ 
               eval(parse(text = paste0(str_split(cur_column(), "_\\d", simplify = T)[1],
                                        "_right", str_split(cur_column(), "malvol", simplify = T)[2]))),
             eval(parse(text = paste0("leftright_",  str_extract(cur_column(), "w.")))) == "right" ~ 
               eval(parse(text = paste0(str_split(cur_column(), "_\\d", simplify = T)[1],
                                        "_left", str_split(cur_column(), "malvol", simplify = T)[2]))))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What makes your problem difficult is that a lot of **information is hidden in variable names rather than data cells**. Hence, you need some steps to transform your data into ["tidy" format](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html). In the code below, the crucial part is (1) to turn the variables `[malvol]_[lr]_[num]_[w]` into four separate columns `malvol`, `lr`, `num`, `w` (all prefixed with `m_`), and (2) from the variables `leftright_[w]` extract variable `w` (prefixed with `l_`) using the functions `pivot_longer` and than `separate`.

```
# Just adding a row_id to your data, for later joining
dt <- dt %>% mutate(id = row_number())

df <- dt %>% 
  # Tidy the column "malvol" 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('malvol'), names_to = "m_var", values_to = "m_val") %>%
  separate(m_var, into = c("m_malvol", "m_lr", "m_num", "m_w")) %>%
  
  # They the column "leftright"
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('leftright'), names_to = 'l_var', values_to = 'l_lr') %>%
  separate(l_var, into = c(NA, "l_w")) %>%

  # Implement the logic
  filter(l_w == m_w) %>%
  filter(l_lr != m_lr) %>%
  
  # Pivot into original wide format
  select(-c(l_w, l_lr, m_lr)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(m_malvol, m_num, m_w), values_from = m_val)

# Merging back results to original data   
dt <- dt %>% mutate(id = row_number()) %>% inner_join(df, by="id")
```

Although I pivoted the data back into your desired format in the end (to check whether results are in line with your desired results), I would suggest you leave the data in the long format, which is "tidy" and more easy to work with, compared to your "wide" format. So maybe skip the last `pivot_wider` operation.

Comment: thanks for your response - after all, I agree that bringing the data into long format is the more transparent way.